# Image from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I have an string coming from service in dictionary having an image data like

```
"profile_image":"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
```

How should i get an image from it?

Comment: UIImage has -initWithData: property use this.

Comment: Looks base64 encoded, at least i get a PNG header if i decode the string as base64.

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
    NSString* yourString = [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"profile_image"];
    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:yourString] 
    //NSData* imageData = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Yes i tried it but still getting image as nil. Its not working.

Comment: Try with this, NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:yourString] use this instead of NSData* imageData = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *word = [[myProfileInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"profile_image"];
                if ([word length]>0)
                {
                    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:word];
                    profileImgViewObj.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];
                }
```